# socket.on State Not Changing while sending socket.emit() in a map React

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm using `socket.io` along with `react` for a project. Here's my component

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import { IProject } from '../../interfaces/projects';
import { IRun } from '../../interfaces/runs';

const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL);

export default function RunAll() {
    const { search } = useLocation();

    // API State
    const [project, setProject] = useState<IProject | undefined>(undefined);
    const [runs, setRuns] = useState<IRun[]>([]);

    // Query Params
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const projectId = queryParams.get('projectId')!;

    // Get Project
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { data: project } = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/projects/${projectId}`);

            setProject(project.data);
        })();
    }, [projectId]);

    // Clear socket
    useEffect(() => () => {
        socket.close();
    });

    const runAllTests = async () => {
        project?.tests.forEach((test) => {
            console.log(test);
            socket.emit('create run', { projectId, testId: test.id, url: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL });
        });

        socket.on('created run', (run: IRun) => {
            console.log(run);
            setRuns([...runs, run]);
        });
    };
    console.log(runs);

    const renderHeader = () => (
        <div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr', alignItems: 'center' }} className='mb-3'>
            <h1 className='heading-primary mt-auto mb-auto'>Run Overview</h1>

            <Button onClick={runAllTests}>Run All Tests</Button>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <main>
            {renderHeader()}
            {runs?.map((run) => (
                <div>{run.id}</div>
            ))}
        </main>
    );
}
```

When the button is click and `runAllTests()` is called, i can see the `console.log(test)` in the console and my server logs also show me that it has received the `socket.emit('create run')`. And when the server responds with `socket.on('created run')`, I can see the value of the created run. However, only the 2nd run(in case of the length of `project.tests` being 2), only the last run is being added to the state.

What am I missing here? Please help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `socket.on('created run', () => {})` executed multiple times for each `socket.emit('create run', ()=> {})` that you fire?

Comment: socket.on('created run', (run: IRun) => {
            console.log(run);
            setRuns([...runs, run]);
        });  use this code in useeffect and make sure it only runs once.

Comment: @ShafqatJamilKhan I will try that

Comment: The `socket.close()` is closing the socket immediately. Why is that? After removing the socket.close(). It is working perfectly. If you post an answer, I can mark it correct and upvote it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Proposed change should not affect the emitting code.  Make sure your server is running and accessible.

Comment: I have also improved my answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    socket.on('created run', (run: IRun) => { console.log(run); setRuns([...runs, run]); });
```

use this code in useEffect and make sure it only runs once. Following should work for you.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import { IProject } from '../../interfaces/projects';
import { IRun } from '../../interfaces/runs';

const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL);

export default function RunAll() {
    const { search } = useLocation();

    // API State
    const [project, setProject] = useState<IProject | undefined>(undefined);
    const [runs, setRuns] = useState<IRun[]>([]);

    // Query Params
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const projectId = queryParams.get('projectId')!;

    // Get Project
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { data: project } = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/projects/${projectId}`);

            setProject(project.data);
        })();
    }, [projectId]);

    // Clear socket
    useEffect(() => () => {
        socket.on('created run', (run: IRun) => {
            console.log(run);
            setRuns([...runs, run]);
        });
        
        return function cleanup () {
           socket.close();
        }

    },[]);

    const runAllTests = async () => {
        project?.tests.forEach((test) => {
            console.log(test);
            socket.emit('create run', { projectId, testId: test.id, url: process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL });
        });

        
    };
    console.log(runs);

    const renderHeader = () => (
        <div style={{ display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr', alignItems: 'center' }} className='mb-3'>
            <h1 className='heading-primary mt-auto mb-auto'>Run Overview</h1>

            <Button onClick={runAllTests}>Run All Tests</Button>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <main>
            {renderHeader()}
            {runs?.map((run) => (
                <div>{run.id}</div>
            ))}
        </main>
    );
}
```